# How to render View as String in ASP.NET CORE 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to render partial view as string and i searched and found this article:

https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string

```
public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
{
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);

        if (viewResult.View == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
        }

        var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
        {
            Model = model
        };

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(
            actionContext,
            viewResult.View,
            viewDictionary,
            new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
            sw,
            new HtmlHelperOptions()
        );

        await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

but inner error happen:

> Message: `Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type`
>
> StackTrace: `at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )\r\n   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )\r\n   at AspNetCore._Views_Shared_Comments_cshtml.<ExecuteAsync>d__39.MoveNext() in /Views/Shared/Comments.cshtml:line 7\r\n--- End of stack trace fr...`

The error with me is in innerException, and I cannot know exactly what is the reason, but i think in that line of code:

```
var viewContext = new ViewContext(
    actionContext,
    viewResult.View,
    viewDictionary,
    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
    sw,
    new HtmlHelperOptions()
);
```

I check line 7 in the view and found some variable not has value and fixed it, but another error appear:

> Message: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index`
>
> StackTrace: ``` at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List``1.get_Item(Int32 index)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelper.GetVirtualPathData(String routeName, RouteValueDictionary values)\r\n   a... ```

Comment: Could you please show your code, the error message says that you're trying to set `null` to a Boolean, because bool is non-nullable.

Comment: my code is exactly as the example in the link, but the error with me is in innerException, and i cannot know exactly what is the reason, but i think in that line of code : var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    viewDictionary,
                    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                    sw,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                );

Comment: Your view has an error in it on line 7.

Comment: CodeCaster, yes i fixed it but another error appear, i update my post

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the exact error but I have 2 suggestions:

**1. Check `viewResult` is NULL or not first**

The `viewResult` might be `NULL` hence viewResult.View might throw `NullReferenceException`. So I would do:

```
if (viewResult == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{ viewname } is not found.");
}
```

**2. `await` on `View.RenderAsync()`**

```
var viewContext = new ViewContext(actionContext,
    viewResult.View,
    viewDictionary,
    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
    sw,
    new HtmlHelperOptions()
);

await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

return sw.ToString();
```

Comment: viewResult in not null, i checked it, and i used await as you said but another error appear after fix the first error, i update my post

Comment: I have the exactly same code beside the checking viewResult vs viewResult.View. And mine runs fine. Did you put your templates under Views/Shared folder?

Comment: yes, Comments.cshtml template is in the shared folder, i checked the viewResult.View.Path by using Break points in debugging it is: "Views/Shared/Comments.cshtml" .... but i want to know which Index it mean in the last error appears?

Comment: awww without debuging in the souce code, its hard to know where the error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After looking at this closer, I realized, that I had used a ViewData in the View, that had no value set. Hence the error "Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type". Checking the value for Null, solved the issue for me and the view generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `Viewbag/Tempdata` at `/Views/Shared/Comments.cshtml:line 7`.

You have not send value from controller to view, in this case it's null so why it's throw the runtime error.